# JavaScript Raphaël, multiple arrays sharing same functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, raphael

New to javascript, using the Raphaël library. The SVG image I'm using has a bunch of different coloured squares. I would like to have different sets (eg. bluepath, pinkpath) for each colour and sharing the same hover and click functions. The popup box works fine, but I'm not sure how to join the multiple arrays to share the same hover and click functions. I would be very grateful if someone would be kind enough to help me out... :)

```js
arr = new Array();
for (var block in bluepaths) {
    var obj = r.path(bluepaths[block].path);
    obj.attr(attributes);
    arr[obj.id] = block, attributes = {
        fill: '#00CCFF',
        stroke: '#3899E6',
        'stroke-width': 1,
        'stroke-linejoin': 'round'
    }
}

arr = new Array();
for (var blocktwo in pinkpaths) {
    var obj = r.path(pinkpaths[blocktwo].path);
    obj.attr(attributes);
    arr[obj.id] = blocktwo, attributes = {
        fill: '#00F',
        stroke: '#3899E6',
        'stroke-width': 1,
        'stroke-linejoin': 'round'
    }

    obj.hover(function () {
        this.animate({ fill: '#fff' }, 300);
    }, function () {
        this.animate({ fill: attributes.fill }, 300);
    }).click(function () {
        document.location.hash = arr[this.id];
        var point = this.getBBox(0);

        $('#map').next('.point').remove();
        $('#map').after($('<div />').addClass('point'));

        $('.point').html(bluepaths[arr[this.id]].name).prepend(
            $('<a />').attr('href', '#').addClass('close').text('Close')
        ).prepend(
            $('<img />').attr('src', 'flags/' + arr[this.id] + '.png')
        ).css({
            left: point.x + (point.width / 2) - 80,
            top: point.y + (point.height / 2) - 20
        }).fadeIn();
    });

    $('.point').find('.close').live('click', function () {
        var t = $(this),
        parent = t.parent('.point');

        parent.fadeOut(function () {
            parent.remove();
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out Raphaël's `set`, it's a logical group capable of obtaining multiple shapes, and designed for the purpose of manipulating many objects with a single call. that seems to be well suited for your needs.

**Example:**

you may use `set`s for binding an event handler to several shapes, like so:

```js
var set = paper.set();

set.push(
    r.circle(240, 120, 60),
    r.rect(50,100,60,60),
    r.path('m160 200 l60 80 l-120 0 z')
);    

set.hover(
    function() {
        // use the magic of hover in!
    },
    function() {
        // do some crazy stuff on hover out!
    }
);
```

**[demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eliranmal/ecFWb/)**

**Reference:**

- [`Set` on the Raphaël official docs](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Set)